# calculating/marking Standard Deviation over a path in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

For this dataset I am trying to mark the SD over the ggplot. But when I am using geom_errorbar it's not marking the SD. Can you please check my code?

```
ID    S1      S2
1   21.09542  71.06014
2   21.09564  71.06064
2   21.09619  71.06128
2   21.09636  71.06242
```

Comment: try without the y argument of `geom_errorbar`

Comment: @mts It not working.  [link](http://postimg.org/image/5b24bu279/)
Here's the o/p. Its same if I include any of the last two lines.

Comment: Instead of piping through a lot of mutate() functions, you can just make one with more arguments - mutate(SD1=sd(S1), SD2=sd(S2) - This works even if the later calculations depend on earlier ones. Also. I don't understand what you are trying to do with the geom_path()

Comment: Haven't you just mixed up your axis variables in the `geom_errorbar` calls?  The variable `s1` is on the x axis, so `mean_s1` should be the errorbar `x` variable and `mean_s2` should be the `y` variable.  Plus, it seems like your vertical error bars from `ymin` to `ymax` should be based on all stats calculated from `s2` and the horizontal error bars on stats from `s1`.

Comment: @JohannesNE geom_path is for the traversing path. 
Can You Provide me any solution to the question asked?

Comment: @aosmith yes, i did tried to alter those. But its not working

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want. You are plotting the data directly, and then want to plot the means by ID with standard deviations visualised on top of that?

Comment: @JohannesNE No, I am plotting the data directly. I have calculated the SD for the s1 and s2. Now, I have plotted the errorbar. for each point using the SD. Like this

geom_errorbar(aes(x=Latitude, ymin=Longitude-std.latitude, ymax=Longitude+std.longitude),width=0.001)

Now I want to cover/fill this area from one point to other (it has nothing to do with the color of the points), something similar to geom_smooth() or stat_summary() function. But I couldn't able to do that properly.

Comment: Okay. I'm not able to help much on that one. You might be able to work something out using geom_polygon. Problem is, that you'll need to weigh the X-SD more on vertical paths, and the Y-SD more on horizontal paths, to get a usefull width of the path. Also, I'm not sure the approch with SDs for single datapoints makes any sense statistically. SDs are used to decribe a group of data, and not the individual points.